# Scale string to fit into label (Java, AWT)

Tags: java, text, awt

I have to write app, which can scale font's size of label and buttons depending on size of entire frame. My idea is to increase size of font until whole text fits into label or button.

How can I check is all string fit to button/label?

Comment: Why AWT (e.g. `Label`) rather than Swing (e.g. `JLabel`)?

Comment: *"I have to write app, which can scale font's size of label and buttons depending on size of entire frame"*  If that were a ***good idea*** it probably would have been already done in Chrome, and FF, and web sites that appear in them, and Word, and the iTunes software, and..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following

```
JComponent c = ... // it can be label, button or any other component
FontMetrics fm = c.getFontMetrics(c.getFont()); // or another font
int strw = fm.stringWidth("My text");
```

I took this example from [Getting string size in java (without having a Graphics object available)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914145/getting-string-size-in-java-without-having-a-graphics-object-available)