# Font dimensions in different object to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm not sure how to ask this, I have a subclass JPanel that draws strings with paintComponent. And I have a class that takes `String string, int xPos, int yPos, Font font` as arguments, the object is then drawn with `g.drawString(text.getstring, etc...)`.

However, the problem is that when the text class is constructed I would like to calculate the width and height of the text based on the string and font given, but the way to do that seems to be by doing this:

```
FontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics(Font);
int height = metrics.getHeight();
int width = metrics.stringWidth(string);
```

the problem is that g has to be the 'Graphics' object from paintComponent, however that doesn't exist in the scope of the class, should I pass it as a parameter to the text class? Or is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: In your own component, use `java.awt.font.TextLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compute the width of a string without the graphics context you are going to use to draw it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914145/getting-string-size-in-java-without-having-a-graphics-object-available).

So you need will need to calculate the string width within your paintComponent method, every time it is called.

However, for an approximation, I use the font size as the height and a fudge factor for the width: `string.length() * fontSize * 0.545f` (where we are working in floats with a scale factor of 100).